# Pandas Dataframe groupby + agg + lambda + unique throwing a ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a table that looks like this called `rev_df`.

```
       pcid     date        rep     rev    new_rev  diff    Period
0      523468   2017-01-01  1127    16.60   0       NaN     1
1      523468   2017-01-02  1127    41.32   0       1       1
2      523468   2017-01-03  4568    52.39   0       1       1
3      523468   2017-01-04  4568    47.31   0       1       2
```

This is the line of code in question that's causing some PROBLEMS™.

```
rev_df_period = rev_df.groupby(['pcid', 'Period']).agg({'date': [np.min,np.max], 
                                                        'rev':np.sum,
                                                        'new_prod_rev':np.sum,
                                                        'historical_sales_rep': lambda x: x.unique()
                                                       })
```

The *`lambda x: x.unique()`* is causing the following error:

**`ValueError: Function does not reduce`**

Through testing, I found that if I change the last agg lambda function to `.nunique()`, it doesn't throw an error.  But I need the **list** of unique `rep` values, not the **number** of values.

Any ideas?

The output should look like this:

```
                new_rev        date              rev      rep
                sum     amin         amax        sum      unique
pcid    Period                      
523468  1       0       2017-01-01   2017-02-01  1026.94  [1127,4568]
        2       0       2017-03-24   2017-03-30  90.00    4568
```

Comment: This is a common problem new pandas users run into. Aggregate is *specifically* meant for reduction function. i.e. functions that go from a Series to a scalar. You're not reducing your data to a scalar so that's why you're running into an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.groupby(['pcid', 'Period']).agg({'date': [np.min,np.max], 
                                                        'rev':np.sum,
                                                        'new_rev':np.sum,
                                                        'rep': lambda x: list(set(x))
                                                       })
```

Output:

```
                     date                 rev new_rev           rep
                     amin        amax     sum     sum      <lambda>
pcid   Period                                                      
523468 1       2017-01-01  2017-01-03  110.31       0  [4568, 1127]
       2       2017-01-04  2017-01-04   47.31       0        [4568]
```

Edit to get proper column naming

```
f = lambda x: list(set(x))
f.__name__ = 'unique'

rev_df.groupby(['pcid', 'Period']).agg({'date': [np.min,np.max], 
                                                        'rev':np.sum,
                                                        'new_rev':np.sum,
                                                        'rep': f
                                                       })
```

Output:

```
                     date                 rev new_rev           rep
                     amin        amax     sum     sum        unique
pcid   Period                                                      
523468 1       2017-01-01  2017-01-03  110.31       0  [4568, 1127]
       2       2017-01-04  2017-01-04   47.31       0        [4568]
```